# How would you parse this with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I havent been able to successfully get the user_id from the following record through the use of javascript. I have had a feeling it is a json string but it simply doesn't my json way...

```
[{"columns":["id","user_id","task","priority"],"values":[[1,1,"Do some stuff",0]]}]
```

this comes from the following after using sql.js which is intended to retrieve data from an sqlite database.:

```
$(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'db/sqlite.db', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
            var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM users");

            //
            var tasks = db.exec("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user_id=1");

            var json = JSON.parse(tasks);
            //console.log(json.columns[1].task);

            //var json = JSON.parse(tasks);

            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = json.columns[0].task;

    };
    xhr.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in incorrect format. A proper `JSON` object should start and end with '{' and '}' respectively.

It should simply be:
{
 "columns":["id","user_id","task","priority"],
 "values":[
   [1,1,"Do some stuff",0]
 ]
}
Notice that the data you've given has an extra pair of square brackets surrounding.

In the case that you cannot make changes to the data structure, note that it is an array and hence, treat it as a JS array, rather than trying to parse it as a JSON, which it is not.

Option #1: If you're forced to use JSON:

```
var json = JSON.parse(tasks[0]);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = json.columns[2]; // this will return "tasks"
// to fetch "Do some stuff" : json.values[json.columns.indexOf("tasks")];
```

Option #2: Treat it as a JS Array:

```
//var json = JSON.parse(tasks);  Simply leave this line commented
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = tasks[0].columns[0].task;
```

Comment: after parsing what I have selected from the db I get the above statement...ill try adding braces by appending them and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, that looks like an awful way to return data. But if that's what you have to work with:

```
var arr = [{"columns":["id","user_id","task","priority"],"values":[[1,1,"Do some stuff",0]]}];

var obj = arr[0];
console.log(obj);

var idx = false;

for( var i in obj.columns ){
  if( obj.columns[i] == 'task' ){
    idx = i;
    break;
  }
}

var task = obj.values[0][idx];
console.log(task);
```

`[...]` indicates an array.
`{...}` indicate an object.

https://jsfiddle.net/wjfy4pem/1/

Throw a bunch of `console.log`s in there to see what your variables are at different points. You could probably play with this a bit and come up with a nicer solution.